# Remove Safari <select> glow but keep caret

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap standard .form-control class for my textfields and select boxes.

I want to remove the glow on Safari, so I added the code to the .form-control class in my custom.css:

```
-webkit-appearance:none;
```

Naturally that removed the glow but also the caret to suggest it it's a dop down and now just looks like a normal text field.

How can I get the caret back but keep the glow from coming back?

```
.form-control {
  -webkit-appearance:none;
}
```

http://pastebin.com/M2raCVrw

is my code as it stands.

Thanks in advance!

Paolo

Comment: Can you post a demo of your code please?

Comment: Sorry here you go! http://pastebin.com/M2raCVrw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try `outline:none` this should remove the outline of the select. This should also work for any input elements